# .htacces Unknown Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

There is somehow a error with my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]</pre>
```

yet I do not know what is wrong!

I am trying to make a permalink connector. So if a user enter "localhost/postin'/profiles/username_here" it will redirect them to a URL similar to this "localhost/postin'/profiles/profile.php?user=username_here"

The error it is producing is:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more information. What is the error? What is not happening that you expect to happen?

Comment: Well, what is this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""` and also why do you have a pre tag at the end?

Comment: To be honest I do not get .htaccess files at all, and I got this example off of the internet. Now I have been doing a little more testing and such, and it looks like the error lies in the last line; RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]</pre>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your rules and try this instead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+)/?$ /profiles/profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hello, I tested this, and it does not do anything. Normally it would atleast test the URL, this time it is not doing anything with it :( It is just saying the URLs I am entering do not exist.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file and what is your document root?